# discord.py 2.0 url_as function doesnt work

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I am  making a bot which has image processing commands from 1.7.3 discord , it used to work perfectly and when i switched to 2.0.1 i get these errors

```py
#as in 1.7.3
asset = Member.avatar_url_as(size=128)
#now in 2.0.1
asset = Member.avatar.url_as(size=128)
```

but the problem is
docs tell that from `Member.avatar_url` its  `Member.avatar.url` but the `url_as` function does not work either what should i do

Comment: Because it doesn't exist... Take a look at the attributes and methods: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Asset

Comment: yes exactly now how im supposed to do image processing like earlier

Comment: ohh i just saw with size fucntion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Documentation they tell that theres a new function called

```py
Member.avatar.with_size(128)
```

is only needed and this will definitely solve your problem
Thank you!